# how to redirect to another aspx page using image button?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have placed an image in one of my mvc 4 aspx application.. now i am not able to redirect to another aspx page suppose "video.aspx". using that image as button..

please help me..

this is my image code:-

```
  <img src="../../Content/myimages/arrow_img11.png" id="videopg"  style=" padding:0px; margin:50px 0px 0px 80px; position:absolute; width:40px; height:32px; z-index:5;"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

J'ust add any of onclick, onMouseDown, onMouseUP:

```
<img src="../../Content/myimages/arrow_img11.png" id="videopg"  style=" padding:0px; margin:50px 0px 0px 80px; position:absolute; width:40px; height:32px; z-index:5;" onclick="window.location.href('http://www.google.de');" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add javascript function as below

```
<img src="../../Content/myimages/arrow_img11.png" id="videopg" onclick="javascript:GotoPage();"  style=" padding:0px; margin:50px 0px 0px 80px; position:absolute; width:40px; height:32px; z-index:5;"  />
```

use below JS code in html head section

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function GotoPage() {

        window.open("video.aspx", "_blank", "", ""); 
    }

</script>
```

Happy Coding...

Comment: its not working.. i already tried java-script.. but now my image got disappeared... this code in not working for ASPX engine